# Lombok with Play 2

Tags: playframework, lombok

What about Lombok integration with Play Framework 2?
I really like [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) it make my code more readable and less boilerplate. And Play Framework is wonderful too. But there is a great trouble in case if you going to mixup them.

Main reason is that scala temlates in play project compiled *before* domain classes. So Lombok, which itself is compiler's hack do not generate accessors for that time.

The question is: if it any ways to make it work?

I found some discussions in [Google](https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/67030ceff3ba26c2) [Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Ojn4EcR6Yns), but they do not provide any reasonable solution. So have you got any success with it?

And.. why guys from Play Framework project do not provide some Lombok-like solution? Anyway Play is full of code-generation magic and shadow compiling... so, why not?

Comment: I am watching at scala and a lot of doubts spining in my head. I think scala is _difficult_. And there is one more reason. It's still hard to find scala developer.

Comment: In my opinion scala is easier than java. (YMMV i learned scala and java at the same time arriving from embedded C). But you are right it is hard to find developers.

Comment: @Fabian IMHO, it is too differs from regular java way. It is not java with steroids, its like another world. Just take a look on _implicit_ tricks. When I wathing scala sources, I have strong feeling "What the..". But this is just my subjective opinion.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/MV11Ru_t4LE/discussion Ben McCann

Comment: @niels thank a lot. Thats what I want to discuss.

Comment: The problem with Lombok and the Play template files (views) has nothing to do with compile order within Play or sbt - it's a problem with the Scala compiler - [see this comment](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4006#issuecomment-81049150) for further explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, workaround is rather simple and was proposed in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/MV11Ru_t4LE/discussion), but there are some obscurity in docs, well I'll describe step-by-step what one should do.

**1. Isolate your domain model logicaly**

This means that domain classes should not call anything from *views* or *controllers*.

**2. Create sub-project which contain domain classes**

Some information given [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/SBTSubProjects). Sub-project is very similar to default play's project, and creating it not so hard. I don't find any tools to do this from play's console, so you need to create some folders by hand.

At first create sub-project folder in main project's folder. Let's assume you name it *domain-data*. Next, create required folders like described in [standart app. layout](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Anatomy). In most cases you want to create simple directory tree in created sub-folder:

```
app
 └ models
    └ myclasses
```

Now move all your domain classes to sub-project's directory tree.

**3.Configuration**

Configuration will be simple enought. Move to the main project's *project* folder and open *Build.scala* file. This is build script for SBT build system.

Define some dependencies at first. Add following strings to your build file:

```
val domainDependencies = Seq(
    "org.projectlombok" % "lombok" % "0.11.4"
)
```

This will add Lombok's jar to your sub-project. Now create sub-project definition:

```
val domainProject = PlayProject(
                            "domain-data", appVersion, domainDependencies, path=file("domain"), mainLang=JAVA
)
```

Where *path* should point to sub-project's folder.

And the last step is updating main project configuration for making it depend on sub-project. Dependence will entails sub-project rebuiling on each main project rebuild.

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).dependsOn(domainProject)
```

After all start main project with *play* command given in terminal, and type *projects* command. You should see your new sub-project.

**4. Profit**

Now it is time to safely refactor your existing code using Lombok.

Comment: Or just try to use scala. It is pain only for about month and pure profit later.

Comment: The question is about Java and a specific problem, telling the guy "or use Scala" is the same as telling him "or use Ruby or Python". Not constructive at all.

Answer (score 0):

My app is "conseillers" (Play 2.2.1 project) and my model is "Conseiller.java" in /app/models

a) Just create two folders and move the "/app/models" folder to the new sub-folder : /models/app/models
[image: make a new directory]
[image: move the folder]

b) add a new build.sbt file to this new folder
[image: create a new sbt file]

c) modify the build.sbt in the root app folder with the .dependsOn (not sure if the .aggregate is 100% necessary) :
[image: modify root build sbt file]

d) check, compile, run
[image: check]

e) see more here [sbt subprojects documentation on Play site](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/SBTSubProjects)